# org-mode can't edit C source code

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I use emacs's org-mode to edit a C program, that is when I edit the below segment:

```
#+begin_src c
#define MAX 100
#+end_src
```

and after I call the function 'org-edit-src-code' to edit the C code in a new buffer, there is an error:

> Language mode `c-mode' fails with: stringp

and I can neither save to nor return to the original buffer after I edit the code in the new buffer.

Every other languages can work without any problem, including C++, elisp, sh.

How can I fix this problem? My org-mode version is 7.6 and emacs version is 23.2.

the full debug info is (follow Noufal Ibrahim's method):

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Language mode `c-mode' fails with: stringp")
  signal(error ("Language mode `c-mode' fails with: stringp"))
  error("Language mode `%s' fails with: %S" c-mode stringp)
  (condition-case e (funcall lang-f) (error (error "Language mode `%s' fails with: %S" lang-f ...)))
  (let ((org-inhibit-startup t)) (condition-case e (funcall lang-f) (error ...)))
  (if (and (setq buffer ...) (if org-src-ask-before-returning-to-edit-buffer ... t)) (org-src-switch-to-buffer buffer (quote return)) (when buffer (with-current-buffer buffer ...) (kill-buffer buffer)) (setq buffer (generate-new-buffer ...)) (setq ovl (make-overlay beg end)) (overlay-put ovl (quote edit-buffer) buffer) (overlay-put ovl (quote help-echo) "Click with mouse-1 to switch to buffer editing this segment") (overlay-put ovl (quote face) (quote secondary-selection)) (overlay-put ovl (quote keymap) (let ... ... map)) (overlay-put ovl :read-only "Leave me alone") (setq transmitted-variables (append transmitted-variables ...)) (org-src-switch-to-buffer buffer (quote edit)) (if (eq single ...) (setq code ...)) (insert code) (remove-text-properties (point-min) (point-max) (quote ...)) (unless (cadr ...) (setq total-nindent ...)) (let (...) (condition-case e ... ...)) (dolist (pair transmitted-variables) (org-set-local ... ...)) (when org-mode-p (goto-char ...) (while ... ... ...)) (when markline (org-goto-line ...) (org-move-to-column ...) (push-mark ... ... t) (setq deactivate-mark nil)) (org-goto-line (1+ ...)) (org-move-to-column (if org-src-preserve-indentation col ...)) (org-src-mode) (set-buffer-modified-p nil) (and org-edit-src-persistent-message (org-set-local ... msg)) (let (...) (when ... ...)))
  (if (not info) nil (setq beg (move-marker beg ...) end (move-marker end ...) msg (if allow-write-back-p ... "Exit with C-c ' (C-c and single quote)") code (or code ...) lang (or ... ...) lang (if ... ... lang) single (nth 3 info) block-nindent (nth 5 info) lang-f (intern ...) begline (save-excursion ... ...) transmitted-variables (\` ...)) (if (and mark ... ...) (save-excursion ... ...)) (if (equal lang-f ...) (setq lang-f ...)) (unless (functionp lang-f) (error "No such language mode: %s" lang-f)) (save-excursion (if ... ...) (setq line ... col ...)) (if (and ... ...) (org-src-switch-to-buffer buffer ...) (when buffer ... ...) (setq buffer ...) (setq ovl ...) (overlay-put ovl ... buffer) (overlay-put ovl ... "Click with mouse-1 to switch to buffer editing this segment") (overlay-put ovl ... ...) (overlay-put ovl ... ...) (overlay-put ovl :read-only "Leave me alone") (setq transmitted-variables ...) (org-src-switch-to-buffer buffer ...) (if ... ...) (insert code) (remove-text-properties ... ... ...) (unless ... ...) (let ... ...) (dolist ... ...) (when org-mode-p ... ...) (when markline ... ... ... ...) (org-goto-line ...) (org-move-to-column ...) (org-src-mode) (set-buffer-modified-p nil) (and org-edit-src-persistent-message ...) (let ... ...)) t)
  (let ((mark ...) (case-fold-search t) (info ...) (full-info ...) (org-mode-p ...) (beg ...) (end ...) (allow-write-back-p ...) block-nindent total-nindent ovl lang lang-f single lfmt buffer msg begline markline markcol line col transmitted-variables) (if (not info) nil (setq beg ... end ... msg ... code ... lang ... lang ... single ... block-nindent ... lang-f ... begline ... transmitted-variables ...) (if ... ...) (if ... ...) (unless ... ...) (save-excursion ... ...) (if ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) t))
  org-edit-src-code()
  (cond ((save-excursion ... ...) (find-file ...)) ((org-edit-src-code)) ((org-edit-fixed-width-region)) ((org-at-table\.el-p) (org-edit-src-code)) ((or ... ...) (call-interactively ...)) (t (call-interactively ...)))
  org-edit-special()
  call-interactively(org-edit-special nil nil)
```

I am a novice and I don't know what the problem is. Any advice?

Comment: Works fine for me with org-mode version 7.5 and emacs 23.3.1. You could enable debugs with `(setq debug-on-error t)` and see if you get something useful in the traceback.

Comment: @noufal Thanks for you advice, the tarceback info is(I don't know how to format the code in comment, the <br\> is add by me to generate a linebreak, but it doesn't work) :<br\> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Language mode `c-mode' fails with: stringp")<br\> 
signal(error ("Language mode `c-mode' fails with: stringp"))<br\> 
error("Language mode `%s' fails with: %S" c-mode stringp)<br\> 
byte-code("\302\303^H   A@#\207" [lang-f e error "Language mode `%s' fails with: %S"] 4)<br\> 
org-edit-src-code()<br\> 
org-edit-special()<br\> 
call-interactively(org-edit-special nil nil)<br\>

Comment: Try reloading Org uncompiled `C-u M-x org-reload` (See: http://orgmode.org/manual/Feedback.html ).  It should give a better backtrace, if not completely resolve the issue if it was related to a badly compiled macro.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin Hi, thanks for you advice. Following you method I get a more detailed backtrace, and I post it above. The problem still exist, and I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Can you use `c-mode` regularly?  i.e. Does `M-x c-mode RET` give an error?  The problem is when `c-mode` is activated there is an error, but org-mode is masking the error.  Just a random thought, but do you have something in `c-mode-hook` that uses `buffer-file-name`?  That might give the error.  In fact, `c-mode-hook` is probably a good place to start looking for problems.

Comment: @IvanAndrus You are awesome! The problem is fixed. I do have a expression in `c-mode-hook` that uses `buffer-file-name`, and after I comment this expression out, the problem disappears. Thanks for your help! By the way, does it means that I can't use `buffer-file-name` in `c-mode-hook`? and how do you know this is the cause of the problem, I am just curious,hehe.

Comment: I have put an answer about how to avoid it.  It will only happen in buffers which have no associated file, which is quite rare in my experience.  But it happened to me with `LaTeX-mode` a few months back, so that's how I suspected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discovered in the comments this is caused by accessing `buffer-file-name` in a temporary buffer which is not backed by a file and hence `buffer-file-name` is nil giving rise the it's failing `stringp`.  Anyway, one way to fix it is by replacing instances of `buffer-file-name` with

```
(or buffer-file-name "DEFAULT-NAME")
```

if you need to use it, or by a block like the following

```
(when buffer-file-name
  (code-going-here-will-only-be-executed-if-buffer-file-name-in-non-nil))
```

Which is easier/better will of course depend upon what you are doing.