# orgmode emacs cannot export to html

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I evaluate a code block (see example below), it works. However; when I tried to export to html I got the next error:
**Wrong type argument: stringp, nil**

If I take the *C* from   -- #+begin_src C -- , it will export without any problem. How I can solve the problem?

Thanks

```
#+begin_src C  :includes <stdio.h> :exports both
int main(void){
printf("hello world");
return 0;
}
#+end_src

#+results:
: hello world
```

Comment: I dont have this problem. try upgrading your orgmode version.

Comment: The org-mode shipped with Emacs 23 is quite old. Your `org-version` could be helpful.

Comment: What version of Org Mode do you have installed?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, org version is 7.8.02. Should I update this version?

Comment: @user1138677 It's worth a try; I tried the export under emacs24, org-version 7.8.03 (git export from 2012 01 23) without a glitch. As a side note: If your system provides "experimental" emacs 24 packages: It is really stable, give it a try.

Comment: FWIW, it Works For Me. Posting an error trace will be helpful. http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

Change in .emacs

```
(let ((file (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)))
```

for

```
(let ((file  (or buffer-file-name "DEFAULT-NAME")))
```

Here is the link for more inf, but the idea is to replace all the instances of buffer-file-name.

[org-mode can't edit C source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325762/emacs-org-mode-cant-edit-c-source-code)